# OTP expiration implementation in Android

Tags: android, one-time-password

I have requirement to implement, In my activity, I receive an OTP for login, the OTP has be expired in 90 seconds.

Questions

1> Is Alarm Manager is best way to implement the 90 second time expiry?

2> If I have received OTP and same time I receive a call and when call is ended  after 90 seconds and when i come back to original
activity , user should be shown a pop up saying OTP has been expired?

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If your OTP is coming from a server, which will verify if it's a valid OTP or not (when user submits it). Let the same api handle the expiry case. For example: response code 200 = valid, 201 = expired, 203 = in valid.

Answer (score 1):

Use CountDownTimer

```
new CountDownTimer(90000, 1000) {
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     Log.d("seconds remaining: " , millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     // Called after timer finishes
 }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TimerTask` like below sample :

```
public class AndroidTimerTaskExample extends Activity {

Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;

        //we are going to use a handler to be able to run in our TimerTask
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            //onResume we start our timer so it can start when the app comes from the background
            startTimer();
        }

        public void startTimer() {
            //set a new Timer
            timer = new Timer();

            //initialize the TimerTask's job
            initializeTimerTask();

            //schedule the timer, after the first 5000ms the TimerTask will run every 10000ms
            timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 10000); //
        }

        public void stoptimertask(View v) {
            //stop the timer, if it's not already null
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
            }
        }

        public void initializeTimerTask() {

            timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {

                    //use a handler to run a toast that shows the current timestamp
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            //get the current timeStamp
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
                            final String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

                            //show the toast
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;  
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strDate, duration);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }}
```

You can change start and stop of Task as per your call and initialise too whenever you want.

Comment: Once I get OTP and if i press home button , whether TimerTask still run or not, since My activity will be stopped state.

Comment: You will manage it by your self by using stop task , whenever you get OTP.